# Can't access the Db instance on RDS using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I created a DB instance on RDS with easy create following [Create DB instance section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html), then I tried to connect to it using pgAdmin according to what is mentioned in [Connecting to a DB Instance Running the PostgreSQL Database Engine section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html).

When I create the sever on PgAdmin I got this error:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> Could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
> Is the server running on host "xxxxxxxxxxxx" (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I checked the [Troubleshooting Connections to Your PostgreSQL Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting) in the documentation but I configured everything well.

The Db instance configuration is mentioned below:

[image: DB instance configuration]

I found a similar question [PGAdmin III cannot connect AWS RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396788/pgadmin-iii-cannot-connect-aws-rds) and the answers mentioned didn't fix my problem.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that the **inbound** traffic to the the DB is only allowed from security group (SG) `sg-1fe9297e`. The is the same SG as the DB instance is using.

Thus you need to ensure that the instances where `pgAdmin` is running also use the **same SG** and are in the same VPC.

However, if you are trying to connect from the outside of the AWS, you need to modify the SG to allow **internet traffic**. Preferably limited to your work/home IP address/range.